# If I plug in an empty USB flash drive — that had deleted files — can a computer save those files so they can be recovered by recovery tool?

Tags: windows, vulnerabilities

I plugged my USB flash drive that I previously deleted my data from to school computer. But I didn't use eraser to clear it so the files cannot be retrieved. Can the school computer have access to those after I unplugged it?

Comment: Nope. Unless a computer is actively scanning a device — like a USF flash drive — for deleted files for recovery, the computer cannot access those deleted files.

Comment: Recovery from flash memory devices is tricky.  Unlike mechanical devices, the firmware itself indicates where a file on the device is being stored.  This means the data could be contained within a cell that cannot be accessed by the data recovery program. The best way to find out, if data recovery is possible, is to try to recover the data.  You will want to do this on a machine that you have permissions to install the software.  You mention a "school computer" which means you won't have that permission or ability to install software on it.

Answer (score 2):

No - Not unless they made a copy of the raw USB disk while it was plugged in, which would seem vanishingly unlikely - it is not something that could happen automatically, and it is a fairly slow procedure - especially on an SD card.  (Hypothetically - If they did want to do this they would likely confront you and demand the SDCard so they know its the correct one and person, and then recover the data - likely involving police or other legal authorities)